# Run a single Android (unit) test from gradle without loading other project dependencies

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, gradle, robolectric

I'm using the [awesome plugin from Jake Wharton](https://github.com/JakeWharton/gradle-android-test-plugin) for Android unit tests. My objective of taking the trouble to get these unit tests running, is for speed (TDD quick feedback and all).

I've manage to configure it correctly and have some sample tests running as follows:

```
./gradlew test
```

Whenever I run the tests though I notice the following output:

```
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
The Test.testReportDir property has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please use the Test.getReports().getHtml().getDestination() property instead.
The TaskContainer.add() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please use the create() method instead.
:mySampleApp:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:mySampleApp:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:mySampleApp:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:facebook:compileLint
:libraries:facebook:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:facebook:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:facebook:packageReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:facebook:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:facebook:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:facebook:prepareReleaseDependencies
:libraries:facebook:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:facebook:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:facebook:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:facebook:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:facebook:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:facebook:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:facebook:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:facebook:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:facebook:compileRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:facebook:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:facebook:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:facebook:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:facebook:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:facebook:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:facebook:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:mySampleApp:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71800Library UP-TO-DATE
:mySampleApp:preparemySampleAppandroidLibrariesFacebookUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:mySampleApp:prepareDebugDependencies
:mySampleApp:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:mySampleApp:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:mySampleApp:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:mySampleApp:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mySampleApp:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mySampleApp:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:mySampleApp:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mySampleApp:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
```

Gradle seems to be loading ALL the dependencies for my project.

My Sample Test is as follows:

```
package com.mycompany.mysampleapp;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.fest.assertions.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class AdditionOperationsTest {
  @Test public void testModulus() {
    assertThat(1).isEqualTo(1);
  }
}
```

This test should actually take a fraction of a second to run. My understanding is that all that pre-loading of the project dependencies is bogging it down.

In the good days, I would make sure i have what i need in the CLASSPATH and just run something like:

```
javac src/test/java/main/java/com/micromobs/pkk/AdditionOperationsTest.java
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.micromobs.pkk.AdditionOperationsTest
```

Considering this is an Android project with gradle, I'm assuming i would have to do something a little different like create specific tasks in the gradle build file, that include only my test files for my sample project, and then run a gradle command ./gradlew taskName ?

## Question: Is it possible to run the single test "AdditionOperationsTest" within the context of my project (com.mycompany.mysampleapp) alone so that it doesn't load the external project dependencies

Here's how my configuration files currently look like:

```
# settings.gradle
include ':libraries:gradle-android-test-plugin'
include ':libraries:facebook', ':mysampleapp'

# build.gradle
...
apply plugin: 'android-test'

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.1.+'
    testCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'
}

# location of my test files:
androidproj/mysampleapp/src/test/java/main/com/mycompany/mysampleapp/AdditionOperationsTest.java
```

Comment: I'm trying to solve this same problem. I think the thing to do is to have multi-module project so that the tests exist in a separate module, but am hoping that won't be necessary.

Comment: Yeah I REALLY don't want to break my tests into different modules. I feel I would lose out on the goodness of having shifted our entire project to gradle. I'm hoping this is just some silly parameter that I have to add in or task that I have to declare, that'll ignore the external project dependencies and run the exact test that I point to and only dependencies that it requires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do so by using the `-a` [command line option](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html) (no rebuild of project dependencies). Executing `gradle -a test` should result in the `libraries:facebook` and `mysampleapp` projects not being rebuilt.

**EDIT:** As noted below you can significantly improve the performance of your Gradle build by using the [Gradle daemon](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html).

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, wow that is totally right. Adding the argument made sure the facebook lib wasn't rebuilt. I notice though, that I only shaved a few mseconds off. Didn't dramatically make my test run faster :( Any tips you can provide to make the test run fast e.g. like a lazy loading of dependencies only if used? The test I have doesn't use any part of the "framework" and so should have run really fast. Cheers.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. How long does your test take to run? You might want to look into why it actually takes as long as it takes at the moment (e.g. does the test make calls to external systems).

Comment: Total time: 10.612 secs. I think it's more to do with the setup because the test class per say is just a dummy test class (exactly the same as the one I posted in the question) which should run instantaneously. I think gradle is recalculating/recompiling or doing something to prepare the whole project before running a single test.

Comment: Once dependencies are downloaded, the check with remote should be fast. BTW: Another tip - do you use the [Gradle daemon](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html)? That should shave off some time as well.

Comment: you my friend, are a rockstar! I was not using the daemon until you mentioned. This cut down my build time from 10 to 3s.

Comment: Can you add the tip of using the gradle daemon in your answer so it's more easily visible to everyone. That is a huge win!